# Interference fit problem in ANSYS Workbench 16.1 - how do I get rid of pressure/displacement raisers?

Tags: structural-engineering, finite-element-method, ansys

I have an interference fit problem of two perfect cylinders modelled in 2D using symmetry. The overall interface pressure is around 20MPa lower than the hand calculations and I get non-uniform displacement / pressure near the edges of the model. Any suggestions on how to remove these raisers would be greatly appreciated!

I've attached the pressure results.
[[image: Pressure distribution]

Comment: I have been trying to get smooth pressure results from contacts for the past 10 years from ANSYS. It is still an ongoing battle.

Answer (score 0):

What are your constraints like? from the proximity it seems that you might be over constrained or at least to have uniform radial stiffness near the edges.

Another option for might be to turn on the `Normal-Projected Normal` option
[image: pic]

To get smooth results you need to try out different contact formulations also, but in my experience you will never get 100% smooth. The best I have ever achieved is pressure results within 10% of the average.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make meshes at the interface similar (number of divisions along the line). If the line is split into multiple, you can combine into one using virtual cells.